# Couldn't install tenserflow on Windows10 with python --version 3.5.3. (64 bit)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

**Trying to install TensorFlow**

**Installing with native pip**

*Error:*

```
C:\Users\Sourav>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

**Installing with Anaconda**

*Error:*

```
C:\Users\Sourav>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Sourav>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Sourav>pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: If you're trying to install it, why do you provide the switch `--upgrade`??

Comment: As at official website of tenserflow it says so.

Comment: BTW I tried pip3 install tensorflow, but the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Finally found a solution.***

**Installing with Anaconda**

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
pip install tensorflow
or
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

It is important to add python=3.5 at the end of the first line, because it will install Python 3.5.

Comment: so, why did you write your answer? if I already answered you in the first place?

Comment: @Paddy your answer didn't solve my problem, this did.

Answer (score 0):

according to google, you probably have an old version of pip, try first

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

try:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

or

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Also, I recommend to use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) package control system, it is easy to use. And you can install tensorflow from there:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Plus, all bug reports you can write directly to googlers here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Comment: I tried.. pip3 install tensorflow, but the same error

Comment: still no luck...                                                                                                             (tensorflow) C:\Users\Sourav>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Sourav>pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: @SrGrace try pip install --upgrade pip, and after install the tensorflow

Comment: also, do you have python **64-bit**?

Comment: Yes, I do have python 64-bit & my pip version is the latest.